# Problems in the use of puppeteer-cluster

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I'm practicing with headless browser and I plan to make a little viewerbot. The goal would be to be able to put a site where a stream is broadcasted and to be able to choose a number of viewers to send on the stream with the possibility to increase the number or to reduce it without relaunching the app.

Currently I have some problems with the use of puppeteer-cluster.

1/ I can't find a way to handle the number of active tasks at the same time, how to add or remove at any time. That is to say my number of viewers in this case. Would [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) be better than [Puppeteer-cluster](https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster/) for my use?

2/ When the tasks of the cluster go live if I have a timeout problem on a single task it's all the others that crash as well. How can I fix that?

3/ Once the task is launched how to make sure that it never ends, that the viewer is on the page without being detected AFK or that the task is finished.

```
const {Cluster} = require('puppeteer-cluster');
const vanillaPuppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const {addExtra} = require('puppeteer-extra')
const Stealth = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')

async function main() {

  const puppeteer = addExtra(vanillaPuppeteer)
  puppeteer.use(Stealth())

  let viewers = 3;
  let live = 'https://a-live-stream.com';

  const browserArgs = [
    '--no-sandbox',
    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
    '--disable-infobars'
  ];

  const proxies = [
    'proxy:port',
    'proxy:port',
    'proxy:port',
  ];

  let perBrowserOptions = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < viewers; i++) {
    perBrowserOptions = [...perBrowserOptions, {args: browserArgs.concat(['--proxy-server=' + proxies[i]])}]
  }

  const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
    puppeteerOptions: {
      headless: false,
      args: browserArgs,
      executablePath: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
    },
    monitor: false,
    puppeteer,
    concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_BROWSER,
    maxConcurrency: viewers,
    perBrowserOptions: perBrowserOptions
  });

  cluster.on('taskerror', (err, data) => {
    console.log(`Error crawling ${data}: ${err.message}`);
  });

  const viewer = async ({page, data: url}) => {
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'})
    const element = await page.$('iframe')
    await element.click()

    console.log('#Viewer live')
    await page.waitFor(3000000)
    console.log('#Closed')
  };

  cluster.queue(live, viewer)
  cluster.queue(live, viewer)
  cluster.queue(live, viewer)


  await cluster.idle()
  await cluster.close()
}

main().catch(console.warn)
```